# install java successfully using the dockerfile however its says java command not found

Tags: docker

Here is my docker file

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN update-alternatives --config java
RUN update-alternatives --config javac
```

when I log into the container using  `sudo docker run -t -i dockerfile` and type java or javac it works. I can see it has been installed successfully however when i run it with the file below it says "java command not found"?

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN update-alternatives --config java
RUN update-alternatives --config javac
ENTRYPOINT ["java" "-jar", "/home/project/hello.jar"]
CMD [""]
```

`sudo docker run -t -i dockerfile`
`java command not found` ?

Comment: There's a big chance the `PATH` is different than you expected. Try using fully qualified pathname to java.

Comment: I can see it is installed in /usr/bin/java under containers volume however when I use absolute path it still doesn't work. Although I would like to find a way to not use absolute path

Comment: Suggestion: Try using an official Java image instead: https://hub.docker.com/_/java

Comment: @ManoMarks We had this discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587850/best-way-to-install-java-8-using-docker yet for some unknown reason his container turns out misconfigured. The java image is the best approach IMO

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ENTRYPOINT ["java" "-jar", "/home/project/hello.jar"]`

You forgot a comma before `"-jar"`.

Comment: you got a sharp eye! That fixes it

Comment: Thanks, me to miss comma.

Comment: how does image even build with an error like this?

Answer (score 5):

you're probably missing the JAVA_HOME and PATH declaration.

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 #This can vary
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

And build the docker image with --no-cache option
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I have set it to the following and I verified these exists at the location specified below
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: can you find java in the container? maybe the path is not what you think it is.

Comment: as I stated in my earlier comment I was able to verify the location of where Java was installed in the container and it looks right

Comment: I've actually just seen a similar issue with an alpine docker image, where java was put in `/opt/jdk/`. It would not find java, and I had to make the java path be `/usr/java/default/` for the image to work. It may be that the program hard codes the java path to be that instead of using the PATH. I don't know, but that fixed it for me.

Comment: I am not using any Java image. I just use apt-get as listed above after failing to install with java:8 image. I have also installed say mysql and I have the same issue which is I cannot specify mysql -h localhost -u abcd -pabcd in the docker file it says mysql command not found but when I log in to the image and do mysql it works so I am not sure whats happening

Comment: you might be having a problem with cache. try rebuilding your image with `-no-cache` and see if it helps.

Comment: Actually I am still facing the same problem with --no-cache

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation. I have installed java from gz file [cd /work && tar zxvf jre-8u141-linux-x64.tar.gz] and set the path using RUN PATH "/work/jre1.8.0_141/bin".
But it does not work [starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH"

I even tried to use CMD /work/jre1.8.0_141/bin/java , this too does not work.