# How to run a jar file using docker image?

Tags: docker

My jar runs on a specific port and I am assuming there is port for the container so how I do run a jar using the docker image? how do these ports communicate with each other? Do I need to expose both of these ports? Do I need both Entrypoint and CMD? My jar file does need to accept any arguments since it can pick the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

If your container does not communicate with the external network (ie. the java program is the only one using those ports) then you do not need to expose the ports. Your entrypoint or cmd can be ~`java -jar /my/jar` and it will use your defaults.

Comment: My jar is an server so it does need to communicated to the external network (sorry I forgot to mention that). but again containers have their own port and applications have their own port? how do they integrate with each other? Finally is it entrypoint or cmd or do I need both?

Comment: In that case, you need to expose and publish the ports. When you expose ports, they become visible to other containers on the Docker bridge network. When you publish and expose ports, they are mapped to ports of the host machine. You can use either entrypoint or cmd depending on your needs. If you use entrypoint, params passed by `docker run` are used as params for your entrypoint. With cmd, params will instead override your cmd.

Comment: I couldn't run the jar file for some reason I keep getting java not found although I can clearly see that it is installed in the location posted in the link below to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608753/install-java-successfully-using-the-dockerfile-however-its-says-java-command-not/36636623?noredirect=1#comment60936506_36636623