# Error while calling python subprocess in docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, subprocess

I'm trying to call a subprocess in python 2.7. This subprocess executes a JAVA jar file and reads the output. I'm using django in a docker container.

I'm calling a function:

```
def call_exec(lang)
  curdir = curdir = 'ht/exec_folder'
  tmp_files_dir = 'ht/temp_files'
  script_args = ["java","-jar",'/'+curdir + "/executable.jar",
        "-l",lang,"-s",'/'+tmp_files_dir]
  output = subprocess.check_output(script_args)
  return output
```

Here, ht is a folder inside my Django app. I'm trying to use executable.jar and read the output. The other arguments are meant for running the executable.
The following is the error produced:

```
django_1    |     similarity = call_exec('english')
django_1    |   File "/app/langswipe/submissions/check_view.py", line 80, in call_exec
django_1    |     output = subprocess.check_output(script_args)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
django_1    |     process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
django_1    |     errread, errwrite)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
django_1    |     raise child_exception
django_1    | OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

There are 2 files in the tmp_files_dir. When I run the executable on my local machine, the same arguments give me a result but this one does not. Any clue on what's happening ?

**EDIT**

The jar is in place but the subprocess call fails. Locally, it's running fine. With comments from experienced professionals, I took a look at the docker file and I realized that Java was missing inside the container. I tried installing Java on this container but the build failed.

I read the following sources to install JAVA on my present container:

[Best way to install java 8 using docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587850/best-way-to-install-java-8-using-docker)

https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2015/08/08/creating-a-docker-image-with-ubuntu-and-java/

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/openjdk/e6e9cf8b21516ba764189916d35be57486203c95/8-jdk/Dockerfile

My modified docker file is :

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# to accomodate slate
RUN easy_install distribute

# Requirements have to be pulled and installed here, otherwise caching won't work
COPY ./requirements /requirements

RUN pip install -r /requirements/production.txt && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/nltk_data && \
    python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data punkt stopwords wordnet averaged_perceptron_tagger && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install poppler-utils -qy



RUN groupadd -r django && useradd -r -g django django
COPY . /app
RUN chown -R django /app

COPY ./compose/django/gunicorn.sh /gunicorn.sh
COPY ./compose/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /gunicorn.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh && chown django /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /gunicorn.sh && chown django /gunicorn.sh


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u111-b14-2~bpo8+1

# see https://bugs.debian.org/775775
# and https://github.com/docker-library/java/issues/19#issuecomment-70546872
ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
        ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

# see CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION notes above
RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure




WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The build fails. I have very limited knowledge of docker as I am new to it and I would appreciate if someone helped me figure out the problem.

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile

Comment: lets check is jar file exists manually. run `docker  exec -it <container_name> bash` and try to execute command like python script

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. I was using the base image of python 2.7 I changed that to ubuntu and installed Java, Python and Ruby which I wanted to use.